# Asymptotic form of pdf of Escape Time of arithmetic fBm

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, open-problems, stochastic-differential-equations

I am trying to apply the Girsanov formula and Doobs optional sampling theorem to obtain an asymptotic form of first passage density of an fbm process with drift, but the answer i am getting seems strange, it does not match the brownian motion case result as well as i assumed it would. I am seeking help in debugging these computations.

I am also very much interested in learning about analytical ways of verifying this result.

Thank You

**Some known results**

The first passage density of Brownian motion case is given by the following theorem.

**Theorem:**
    Let the arithmetic Brownian motion process $X \left(t\right)$ be defined by the following Brownian motion driven SDE
    \begin{equation}
 \mbox{d}X \left(t\right) =  a \mbox{d}t + b \mbox{d}{W}\left(t\right).
 \end{equation}
    with initial value $X_0$. Let $\tau =\inf \left(u |X(u) \le B\right)$ denote the first passage time for the barrier $X_0 < B$. Then the first passage time $\tau$ is distributed as Inverse Gaussian Distribution
    \begin{equation}
 \tau \sim IG\left(\frac{B - X_0}{a}, \frac{\left(B - X_0\right)^2}{b^2}\right),\label{abmFirstPassageDist}
 \end{equation}
    and for $t > 0$ the pdf of $\tau$ is
    \begin{equation}
 f(t) = \sqrt{\frac{(B - X_0)^2}{2 \pi b^2 t^3}} \exp\left[-\frac{ \left(at - B + X_0\right)^2}{2 b^2 t}\right]\label{abmFirstPassageDensity}.
 \end{equation}

**The Girsanov formula for fBm** Let $B^H \left(t\right)$ denote fractional brownian motion with mean $0$ and variance $t^{2H}$, for all $H \in \left(0, 1\right)$ defined on $\left(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}\right)$. Let $a$ be a scalar. Define a new probability measure $\mathbb{Q}$ on $\left(\Omega, \mathcal{F}\right)$ via the Radon Nikodym derivative with respect to $\mathbb{P}$ \begin{equation}
 \frac{\mbox{d}{\mathbb{Q}}}{\mbox{d}{\mathbb{P}}} = \exp\left\{a M_T - \frac{1}{2}{a}^2 \langle M, M\rangle_T \right\}\label{girsanovRadonNikodymDerivativeWithInnerProduct}
 \end{equation}
    where
    \begin{equation}
 M_T = \frac{1}{2 H \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2} - H\right) \Gamma \left(H + \frac{1}{2}\right)} \int_0^T \left(s\left(T - s\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{2} - H} \mbox{d}{{B_s}^H}.
 \end{equation}
    The process $M_T$ is a martingale with independent increments, zero mean and variance function $c^2 T^{2 - 2H}$ where
    \begin{equation}\label{c}
 c = \sqrt{\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2} - H\right)}{2 H \left(2 - 2H\right)\Gamma\left(H + \frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(2 - 2H\right)}}.
 \end{equation}
    Then the process defined, for all $t \in \left[0, T\right]$, by $B^H \left(t\right) + a t$  is the standard $\mathbb{Q}$-fractional Brownian motion on $\left[0, T\right]$. In other words, under probability measure $\mathbb{Q}$,
    $B^H \left(t\right)$ restricted to $t \in \left[0, T\right]$ is distributed as an arithmetic fractional Brownian motion with drift $a$.

A proof of the Girsanov formula for fractional Brownian motion can be found in [Norros's paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bj/1171899318), where the term the fundamental martingale is also coined for the process $M_t$. It's noteworthy that using the variance of $M_t$, Radon Nikodym Derivative can also be re-written as
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mbox{d}{\mathbb{Q}}}{\mbox{d}{\mathbb{P}}} = \exp\left\{a M_T - \frac{1}{2}{a}^2 c^2 T^{2 - 2H} \right\}.\label{girsanovRadonNikodymDerivative}
\end{equation}

**corollary**
    Let $X\left(t\right) = b B^H \left(t\right)$ be an arithmetic fractional brownian motion with volatility $b$, for all $H \in \left(0, 1\right)$ defined on $\left(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}\right)$. Let $a$ be a scalar. Define a new probability measure $\mathbb{Q}$ on $\left(\Omega, \mathcal{F}\right)$ via the Radon Nikodym derivative with respect to $\mathbb{P}$
    \begin{equation}
 \frac{\mbox{d}{\mathbb{Q}}}{\mbox{d}{\mathbb{P}}} = \exp\left\{\frac{a}{b} M_T - \frac{1}{2}\frac{a^2}{b^2} c^2 T^{2 - 2H}\right\}.\label{scaledGirsanovRadonNikodymDerivative}
 \end{equation}
    Then the process defined, for all $t \in \left[0, T\right]$, by $Z \left(t\right) = X \left(t\right) + a t$  is an arithmetic $\mathbb{Q}$-fractional Brownian motion process on $\left[0, T\right]$ with volatility $b$. In other words, under probability measure $\mathbb{Q}$, $X\left(t\right)$ restricted to $t \in \left[0, T\right]$ is distributed as an arithmetic fractional Brownian motion with drift $a$ and volatility $b$.

**Proposition**
    Let $B^H \left(t\right)$ denote scaled fractional brownian motion with
    mean $0$ and variance $b^2 t^{2H}$, for all $H \in \left(0, 1\right)$
    with respect to measure $\mathbb{P}$. Define $\tau_k = \inf \left\{t \ge
 0 : B^H \left(t\right) = k\right\}$ for $k > 0$. Then the conditional
    mean and variance of $M_t$ given $B_t$ are
    \begin{equation}
 E\left(M_t | B^H \left(t\right) = k \right) = {t^{1-2H} k \over b}
 \end{equation}
    and
    \begin{equation}
 \hbox{Var}\left(M_t | B^H \left(t\right) = k\right) = t^{2-2H}\left(c^2-1\right).
 \end{equation}

**Proof**
    Both $B^H \left(t\right)$ and $M_t$ have mean zero, the variance
    of $B^H \left(t\right)$ is $b^2 t^{2H}$, the variance of $M_t$ is $c^2 T^{2 - 2H}$, 
    and their covariance $bt$, can be derived
    similarly to, as in Proposition 3.2, in [Norros's paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bj/1171899318). Hence
    the correlation coefficient $\rho$ between $M_t$, $B^H \left(t\right)$
    is $1/c$.  Therefore, using elementary results for the bivariate normal
    distribution, we find
    \begin{eqnarray}
 E\left(M_t | B^H \left(t\right) = k \right) &=&  {\rho \sigma_{M_t}\over \sigma_{B^H \left(t\right)}}k\\\nonumber
 &=& {t^{1-2H} k \over b}\nonumber
 \end{eqnarray}
    and
    \begin{eqnarray}
 \hbox{Var}\left(M_t | B^H \left(t\right) = k\right) &=& {\sigma^2}_{M_t}\left(1 - \rho^2\right) \\\nonumber
 &=& t^{2-2H}\left(c^2-1\right).\nonumber
 \end{eqnarray}

**The Derivation Attempt**
By Doob's optional sampling theorem (justified by the uniform integrability of the martingale
\begin{equation}
\exp\left\{\frac{a}{b} M_T - \frac{1}{2}\frac{a^2}{b^2} \langle M, M\rangle_T\right\}\nonumber
\end{equation}
on $\left[0, T\right]$
and the fact that $\left\{\tau_k \le T \right\} \in \mathcal{F}_{\tau_k}
\cap \mathcal{F}_{T}  = \mathcal{F}_{\tau_k \bigwedge T} \subseteq \mathcal{F}_T$ ),
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{E}\left[\left.\exp\left\{\frac{a}{b} M_T - \frac{1}{2}\frac{a^2}{b^2} \langle M, M\rangle_T\right\} \right| \mathcal{F}_{\tau_k \bigwedge T}\right]
= \exp\left\{\frac{a}{b} M_{\tau_k \bigwedge T} - \frac{1}{2}\frac{a^2}{b^2} \langle M, M\rangle_{\tau_k \bigwedge T}\right\}.
\end{equation}
Therefore,
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{P}^{a,T}\left[\tau_k \in (t,t+dt)\right] &=& \mathbb{E}^{a,T} \left[ 1_{\left\{\tau_k \in (t,t+dt)\right\}} \right]\\
\nonumber
&=&  \mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left\{\frac{a}{b} M_T - \frac{1}{2}\frac{a^2}{b^2} \langle M, M\rangle_T\right\}1_{\left\{\tau_k \in (t,t+dt)\right\}}\right]
\end{eqnarray}
by Corollary above
\begin{eqnarray}
\nonumber
&=& \mathbb{E}\left[\left.\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left\{\frac{a}{b} M_{\tau_k \bigwedge T}
- \frac{1}{2}\frac{a^2}{b^2} \langle M, M\rangle_{\tau_k \bigwedge T}\right\} \right|{\cal F}^{B^H}_{\tau_k\wedge T}\right]1_{\left\{\tau_k \le T\right\}}\right]\\
\nonumber
&=& \mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left\{\frac{a}{b} M_{\tau_k} - \frac{1}{2}\frac{a^2}{b^2} \langle M, M\rangle_{\tau_k}\right\}1_{\left\{\tau_k \le T\right\}}\right]\\
\end{eqnarray}
by Doob's sampling theorem
\begin{eqnarray}
\nonumber
&=& \mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left\{\frac{a k}{b^2}{\tau_k}^{1-2H} - \frac{1}{2}\frac{a^2}{b^2} {\tau_k}^{2-2H}\left(c^2 - 1\right)\right\}1_{\left\{\tau_k \le T\right\}}\right]\\
\end{eqnarray}
by propostion above
\begin{eqnarray}
\nonumber
&=& \int_0^T \exp\left[\frac{a k t^{1-2H}}{b^2} - \frac{1}{2}\frac{a^2 t^{2 - 2H}}{b^2} \left(c^2 - 1\right)\right] \mathrm{P}\left[\tau_k \in \mbox{d}{t}\right].
\end{eqnarray}
On the other hand, $\left\{B^H \left(t\right) + a t\right\}_{t \in \left[0, T\right]}$ is a scaled fractional Brownian motion under $\mathbb{P}^{a,T}$, so
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}^{a,T} \left[\tau_k \le T\right] = \mathbb{P}\left[\hat{\tau_k} \le T\right],
\end{equation}
where $\hat{\tau_k}$ is the first hitting time of the level $k$ of the scaled fractional Brownian motion
with drift $a$. Using the formula for asymptote of the first passage density of fBM without drift due to Molchan, it follows immediately that the long-time form of the first passage time density for fBm with drift is given by
\begin{eqnarray}
f\left(t\right) &=& \exp\left[\frac{a k t^{1-2H}}{b^2} - \frac{1}{2}\frac{a^2 t^{2 - 2H}}{b^2} \left(c^2 - 1\right)\right] t^{H-2}.\label{firstPassageDensityArithmeticFbm}
\end{eqnarray}

[image]

It is noteworthy that $C^2$ has a minimum at $H =\frac{1}{2}$, where $c^2 = 1$.

**Verification Against Brownian motion case**
Upon substituting $H = \frac{1}{2}$ in  $c^2$ evaluates to $1$, and  the function reduces to 
\begin{eqnarray}
f_{H = \frac{1}{2}}\left(t\right) &=& \exp\left[\frac{a k}{b^2}\right] t^{-\frac{3}{2}}.
\end{eqnarray}

This seems a bit off as according to "Brownian motion and stochastic calculus" books, it should be 
\begin{eqnarray}
f'_{H = \frac{1}{2}}\left(t\right) &=& \exp\left[\frac{a k}{b^2} - \frac{a^2}{2b^2}t \}\right] t^{-\frac{3}{2}}.
\end{eqnarray}
The presence of $c^2 - 1$ seems to prevents a perfect match with the Brownian motion case.

Comment: The density $f'_{H=1/2}$ is not a PDF: it is neither integrable nor does it integrate to $1$.

Comment: It is an asymptotic form of the density not the actual density

Comment: Could you define what you mean by *asymptotic form of the density*?

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee , I do n't have a good precise definition of the 
Asymptotic form handy, I will search for it, but in essence it is the function obtained as an approximation of  pdf, which captures how the density scales as function of $t$, for large $t$. I think it is also known as "long time form".

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee I have added a theorem which precisely states the pdf result for arithmetic Bm case, which is well known all ready, pardon the variables used in the two results may be a little different, so in case of arithmetic BM. i guess $f'_{H=\frac{1}{2}}$ gives the asymptotic form of the pdf given in the theorem.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Thank you, I really appreciate your help. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $b=1$, for simplicity.

According to the OP, $(B^H_t)_{t \ge 0}$ is a standard fractional Brownian motion with parameter $H \in (0,1)$ under probability measure $\mathbb{P}$, and the measure $\mathbb{Q}$ is defined by $$
\frac{d \mathbb{Q}}{d \mathbb{P}} (B^H_{[0,T]}) =\exp\left(a M_T -\frac{1}{2} a^2 c^2 T^{2-2H}\right) \;.
$$

By Girsanov's Theorem for fractional Brownian motion (see Thm 4.1 in the reference given below), \begin{align*}
\mathbb{Q}(A) = \mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{Q}}(I(A)) &= \mathbb{E}_{P}\left\{ I(A) \frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d \mathbb{P}} \right\} \\
&=\mathbb{E}_{P}\left\{ I(A) \exp\left(a M_T -\frac{1}{2} a^2 c^2 T^{2-2H} \right)\right\} \\
&= \mathbb{E}_{P}\left\{ I(A) \exp\left(a M_T -\frac{1}{2} a^2 c^2 T^{2-2H} \right) \right\} \\
&= \mathbb{E}_{P}\left\{ \exp\left(a M_T -\frac{1}{2} a^2 c^2 T^{2-2H} \right) \mid A \right\} \mathbb{P}(A)
\end{align*}
If $A=\{ \tau_k \in (t, t+d t) \}$, then $$
\mathbb{E}_{P}\left\{ \exp\left(a M_t -\frac{1}{2} a^2 c^2 t^{2-2H}\right) \mid A \right\} = \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} a t^{1- 2H} (-2 k+a t) \right) 
$$
which follows from the elementary lemma given below with $X = M_t$, $Y=Z_t$, $\sigma_X^2 = c^2 t^{2-2 H}$, $\sigma_Y^2 = t^{2 H}$, and $\rho = 1/c$.

> **Lemma** Let $X$ and $Y$ be centered, normal random variables with variances $\sigma_X^2$ and $\sigma_Y^2$ (respectively), and correlation coefficient $\rho$.  Then $$
> \mathbb{E}\{ e^{a X} \mid Y=k \} = e^{\frac{a \sigma_X}{2 \sigma_Y} (2 k \rho + a (1-\rho^2) \sigma_X \sigma_Y )} \;.
> $$

I surmise that this lemma was the main missing ingredient in the OP's derivation attempt.  It is easy to check that one recovers the standard Brownian motion result when $H=1/2$.

**Reference**

*Norros, Ilkka; Valkeila, Esko; Virtamo, Jorma*, [**An elementary approach to a Girsanov formula and other analytical results on fractional Brownian motions**](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bj/1171899318), Bernoulli
   5, No.4, 571-587 (1999).

Comment: Thank you so much, i see the mistake in my approach. I had gotten confused, if i needed to use the conditional variance as you can see. It makes sense. I will like to submit this derivation to a "letters" like Journal, it will be awesome, if you will be a co-author. I'll write it up. you just have to review Thoughts ?

Comment: Sounds good --- email me details when you're ready.

Comment: See https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0606086.pdf  for related work.

Comment: Thank your for sharing the link. I was familiar with that work, i will try cite it in the literature review section. I have sent you an email just now, please let me know, if you got it.